# discerning who "擦れ違う者" is with minimal context

Tags: reading-comprehension

These are literally the first couple of lines, so all context is within the following.

> 尽きることのない青い空の下――
>
> 蝉が騒がしく鳴いている。
>
> 閑静な町を包む季節の音はどこまでも響き渡り、焼けただれたアスファルトからは陽炎が立ち上ぼる。
>
> 夏の太陽に照らされた坂道を転びそうになって走る少年がいる。
>
> うだるような暑さの中、夢中で向かう先にはなにがあるというのだろう……
>
> 擦れ違う者は、盛夏の輝きを背負って走る少年を仰ぎ見ていた。
>
> 溜息混じりの他人の視線など気にすることなく、少年はただ走る。
>
> 少年は、走ってゆく。

up to these two lines in particular:

うだるような暑さの中、夢中で向かう先にはなにがあるというのだろう……

擦れ違う者は、盛夏の輝きを背負って走る少年を仰ぎ見ていた。

- from who's perspective it the first observation made?
- "擦れ違う者" is looking upwards at the running boy, but what is it? It is a non-omniscient narrator or a yet to be named 3rd party?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perspective of the first observation is simply the narrator of the story.

A translation: "What exactly is waiting for him to cause him to run under the sweltering heat?"

擦れ違う者 is just passersby that saw the boy recklessly running down the hill. It's not any character specifically, just a general group of people.